# Передача словаря через DetailView

Tags: django

Есть четыре страницы: *Блог, Теги, О программе, Обратная связь*, две из них генерируются через **`views.py`** и им передаётся через **`render_to_response()`** "`this_page`", и две через **`DetailView`**.

В общем: можно ли как-то передать "`this_page`" через **`DetailView`** или как это сделать иначе.

---

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="{% if this_page == "blog" %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="/blog">
            Блог<br>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="{% if this_page == "tags" %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="/tags">
            Теги<br>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="{% if this_page == "about" %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="/about">
            О программе<br>
        </a>
    </li>
        <li class="{% if this_page == "contact" %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="/about">
            Обратная связь<br>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):

    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyModelDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['this_page'] = 'about'  # 'contact'
        return context
    ...
```